# Wordpress - custom navigation item classes

Tags: php

I am trying to create something that looks roughly like this:

```
<nav class="site-navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="c1"><span class="icon-paw"></span>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="c2"><span class="icon-quill"></span></span>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="c3"><span class="icon-wool2"></span>Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button id="menu" class="menu-button" type="button" role="button" aria-label="Menu Toggle">
      <span class="icon-menu"></span>
    </button>
</nav>
```

Given that I am placing the button inside the navigation for mobile is controversial, however at the moment it's the least of my worries. I can't work out how to get custom classes on to my nav items. I'm using Bones as a starting point for my project and I've got most things figured out, but this one, after much googling is still to be resolved.

The current function that does my nav is:

```
function bones_main_nav() {
    // display the wp3 menu if available
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'container' => false,                           // remove nav container
        'container_class' => 'menu clearfix',           // class of container (should you choose to use it)
        'menu' => __( 'The Main Menu', 'bonestheme' ),  // nav name
        'menu_class' => 'nav top-nav clearfix',         // adding custom nav class
        'theme_location' => 'main-nav',                 // where it's located in the theme
        'before' => '',                                 // before the menu
        'after' => '',                                  // after the menu
        'link_before' => '',                            // before each link
        'link_after' => '',                             // after each link
        'depth' => 0,                                   // limit the depth of the nav
        'fallback_cb' => 'bones_main_nav_fallback'      // fallback function
    ));
} /* end bones main nav */
```

Any help with this would be VERY much appreciated.

Because it's such a custom navigation that very specific, would I be better to just make a static nav?

Comment: you need to use a custom walker. I'd suggest you ask on the wordpress stackexchange site. Or simply google it. There's plenty of information, like here for instance: http://illuminatikarate.com/blog/how-to-output-custom-html-in-wordpress-menus-using-a-custom-nav-walker/

Comment: You should also read up on wp_nav_menu(): http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: I don't understand do you want to add a `custom class` to your nav items or add a button?

Comment: Looks like a near duplicate of this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/130359/21376 But is looks like you are adding more than just classes. There is a `<span>` in that code.