# Add class to all list items of wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, list

I have a `wp_nav_menu` to which I want to add a classes to the list items.
I know this can be done by choosing 'css classes' from the screen options menu, but then I have to give every single `li` a class.

I have a 2 depth menu.
(for example)

- All the normal li's I want to give the class lidepth1
- All the sub menu li's I want to give the class lidept2

Is this possible in the `wp_nav_menu` function?
I searched the codex but I only found "link before" and "link after" but I don't think that is what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [`nav_menu_css_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class) filter. It is trivial to add classes.

```
function add_classes_wpse_130358($classes, $item, $args) {
  $classes[] = 'new-class';
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class','add_classes_wpse_130358',1,3);
```

But you will probably need to extend `Walker_Nav_Menu` or use the `walker_nav_menu_start_el` filter instead, since the `nav_menu_css_class` filter mysteriously does not have access to the `depth` variable. But `walker_nav_menu_start_el` doesn't let you set the classes where you need to, so assuming your PHP is new enough...

```
function depth_classes_wpse_130358($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
  add_action(
    'nav_menu_css_class',
    function() use ($depth) {
      $depth++;
      $classes[] = "depth-{$depth}";
      return $classes;
    }
  );
  return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el','depth_classes_wpse_130358',1,4);
```

You will get a `depth-N` for every level greater than 0.

I don't recall ever needing to do this. The existing markup has always been sufficient, but there you go.

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed what I was looking for .
But at the end iI decided to use the screen options > css classes.
But it can come in handy in the future.
The reason I wanted this is because I recieved a html template with static classes